# Building Daemon or Service Apps with Office 365 mail — Secret Upload Automation

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory

I am capable of retrieve app token by authenticating with a certificate on the client side and its secret in Azure AD.
My question is, is it possible to upload the application's certificate secret to Azure AD automatically?
I have achieved the automation of AD Application Creation via Powershell Cmdlet, now I'm trying to push the auotmation to the next level.

Further question is, can the consent process also be automated? I understand username/password has to be manual, but can the other part of the process be automated porbably via Powershell Cmdlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostafa is correct that there is no way to automate the consent process.

However, you can automate setting a certificate credential on the app.

Once you've signed in with 'connect-msolservice' and found your application principal id with 'Get-MsolServicePrincipal', you can do the following to set a certificate credential on that application.

```
PS C:\windows\system32> $cer = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate
PS C:\windows\system32> $cer.Import("Path to Certificate (.cer) file")
PS C:\windows\system32> $binCert = $cer.GetRawCertData()
PS C:\windows\system32> $credValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($binCert);

PS C:\windows\system32> New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId 
   "Application Principal ID from above" -Type asymmetric -Value $credValue 
   -StartDate $cer.GetEffectiveDateString() -EndDate $cer.GetExpirationDateString() -Usage verify
```

afterward you can verify that it was successfully set via 'Get-MsolServicePrincipal'.

Comment: Thanks so much, unfortunately I don't have time to verify it today, allow me some more time this weekend please.

Comment: Hello Rich, after I run those lines, the downloaded manifest has empty keyCredentials, is this correct? 

The -AppPrincipalId is the application's Client ID, as recommended by this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential/),

Comment: This is that line : ` 

    New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId e8bfa9eb-f03e-4fce-abee-439b8d359eff -Type asymmetric -Value $credValue -StartDate $cer.GetEffectiveDateString() -EndDate` $cer.GetExpirationDateString() -Usage verify

Comment: Hi Ree5un, I think the confusion here is between your tenant specific service principal and your global application object. Take a look at [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-application-objects/) for a quick summary. Anyway, the reason you do not see the new key on your manifest is because MSOL PowerShell actually only updates your local, tenant specific service principal. If you want to programmatically update your global application object (which means the key you are adding can be used in any tenant), then you will have to use the Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

No and the reason is for security purposes; a user should be allowing an app to access certain permissions from the o365 tenant services. 
Hope this helps.